# Check if email is digitally signed using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, mapi, smime

I would like to know if it's possible, using VB.Net, to check if an e-mail is digitally signed and who is the issuer of the certificate.

Using Extended MAPI Wrapper and Cryptography I was able to get the smime.p7m attachment from an e-mail and get the certificate information out of it (including the issuer), so it seemed like everything was working. The issue is that if I send an unsigned e-mail and manually attach a smime.p7m file, it will trick the code into thinking that the e-mail is signed.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I can also use other methods like Outlook Interop.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Object Model always tries to represent signed and encrypted messages as regular `MailItem` objects. The `MessageClass` property will return "`IPM.Note"`. It goes as far as returning a fake `IMessage` object from the `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` property.

If you are using Extended MAPI, you can read the `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` property and check if its value corresponds to one of the signed/encrypted message classes (e.g. `"IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned"`). Just make sure to unwrap the `IMessage` object if you are retrieving it from the `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` property.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) and and its [RDOEncryptedMessage](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoencryptedmessage.htm) object - it allows to decrypt an encrypted message using `RDOEncryptedMessage.GetDecryptedMessage`  message as well as access the certificate properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a truly signed S/MIME message, then the "smime.p7m" attachment will either have a `Content-Type` value of `application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data` -or- it will have a `Content-Type` value of `application/pkcs7-signature` and will be the 2nd child MIME part of a `multipart/signed` container.

To visualize:

Option 1:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type="signed-data"; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Option 2:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; boundary="some-bounary-string"; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"

--some-boundary-string
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the message content that was signed...

--some-boundary-string
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

...
--some-boundary-string--
```

I'm not familiar with the Exchange MAPI wrapper API, but there should be a way to get the `Content-Type` value. Depending on what that is, you can check for the other attributes I mentioned above to verify if it is actually a signed message or just an attachment.

Note: They can also be `application/x-pkcs7-mime` and `application/x-pkcs7-signature`, but other than the leading `x-` of the MIME subtype, the logic is the same.

Comment: But if I send a signed email and download it's smime.p7m file, it will have all this information that you said, and I can re-attach it to some other e-mail to make the code think that it's signed, I would just have to identify/modify the body part of the smime file (Content-Type: text/html) and keep the same certificate data.

Comment: You're not making any sense. If you take the smime.p7m signature data from 1 message and add it to another message with a different text/html content, then it won't magically become a signed message. It won't even *look* that way unless you create a multipart/signed container that contains the text/html *and* the smime.p7m data with the correct Content-Type (if you try to attach a smime.p7m file using a mail client, it'll have a Content-Type of application/octet-stream, not application/pkcs7-signature - the mail client also won't add it to a multipart/signed, it'll add it to a multipart/mixed)

Comment: Is it possible for someone with my level of knowledge to construct a message that will fool a client or library into thinking that a message *looks* signed when it isn't? Sure, but that's why you implement logic to *verify* the digital signature.